# Firefox protocols and Google advanced search operators

Tags: firefox, google-search

When using the Firefox location bar as my search box I can't use advanced search operators like ***site:**google.com hello* because this warning box pops up.

[image]

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the order in the bar.

Instead of typing in

```
site:google.com hello
```

use this:

```
hello site:google.com
```

This is also true for Google Chrome.

Comment: thanks, now I feel like an idiot :) I won't mark it as the answer just yet.

Comment: Heh, no stupid questions just stupid answers :)  Yeah, this is among my list of things things that makes you go "huh?".

Answer (score 0):

What I did was make a bookmark for a google search, fill in the following fields:

```
Name: google
Location: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s&aq=f&oq=undefined
Keyword: g
```

Then just type 'g site:somwhere.com something' in the address bar and it will work.